# How to programmatically determine checkered status in checkered pattern?

Tags: javascript, css, algorithm, formula

So, I have a `2xN` component grid, where `N` is the number of products. The background colour of the products should be layed out in a checkered pattern, as such:
[image]

Each component has access to its own order (index) of the grid, so, logically, we need to target (for white):

`2,3,6,7,10,11`

And so on.

How can we do this mathematically?

Comment: You say the grid is 2xn and each compoenent has access to its own index. Surely black / white would be decided on if the index was even or odd

Comment: @TKoL Are you serious? It's not even/odd...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be done in CSS with

```
.grid .product{background:black}
.grid .product:nth-child(4n+2),
.grid .product:nth-child(4n+3){background:white}
```

In programmatic terms, you can test for the 4n+2 or 4n+3 by testing if the modulo of the element by 4 is 2 or 3.

So assuming `n` is the index of the element to test

```
var mod = n % 4;
if (mod === 2 || mod === 3) {
    // handle white
} else {
    // handle black
}
```

---

Full example (HTML/CSS)

```css
.grid{
  display:flex;
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  border:1px solid black;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.grid .product {
  color:white;
  background: black;
  width:50%;
  padding:2em;
  text-align:center;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.grid .product:nth-child(4n+2),
.grid .product:nth-child(4n+3) {
  color:black;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<ul class="grid">
  <li class="product">1</li>
  <li class="product">2</li>
  <li class="product">3</li>
  <li class="product">4</li>
  <li class="product">5</li>
  <li class="product">6</li>
  <li class="product">7</li>
  <li class="product">8</li>
</ul>
```